# Image of linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was trying to do this exercise and I don't know if what I did is okay or not.
Let $T:P_2[\mathbb R] \to \mathbb R^4$ be a linear transformation and let $B=\{1 + x^2, x, 2x + 1\}$ and 
$$B'=
    \{(0,0,1,3), 
    (0,1,1,0), 
    (1,1,2,1), 
    (1,0,0,2)\}$$
be bases of $P_2[\mathbb R]$ and $\mathbb R^4$, respectively. 
If the matrix representing $T$ is
$M =\left[\matrix{1&3&2\cr 0&1&1\cr 1&2&1\cr 2&4&2\cr}\right]$,

a)Find the bases $\ker (T)$ and ${\rm Im} (T)$. Check dimension theorem.

a)First of all I did this - rename the basis
$B=\{u_0,u_1,u_2\}$ and
$B'=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$.
So:
$$\eqalign{T(u_0) &= v_1 + v_3 + 2v_4\cr
    T(u_1) &= 3v_1 + v_2 + 2v_3 + 4v_4\cr
    T(u_2) &= 2v_1 + v_2 + v_3 + 2v_4\cr}$$

Then, row reduce the given matrix to get the kernel, so:
$$\left[\matrix{1&0&-1\cr 0&1&1\cr 0&0&0\cr 0&0&0\cr}\right] \left[\matrix{a\cr b\cr c\cr}\right] = \left[\matrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr0\cr}\right]$$
$a - c =0$ and 
$b + c=0$, so $a=c, b=-c$, so a basis is $\left\{\pmatrix{1\cr -1\cr 1\cr}\right\}$.

Then, for the image I did this:
$$\eqalign{
    a + 3b + 2c &= w\cr
    b + c &= x\cr
    a + 2b + c &= y\cr
    2a + 4b + 2c &= z\cr}$$
After gauss, finally reached to $w=x +y$ -- I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Your kernel basis is correct. To find a basis for the image, you need the column space of $M$. You should have learned how to do this, right before this exercise.

Comment: Well, i never did an exercise like this. Can explain me what to do now to get the image?Is the kernel okay or i need to express it as a polynomial form?

Comment: To find the column space of a matrix $A$, you find the RREF, and then pick the columns from $A$ that have a pivot. There are pivots in columns 1 and 2 of your RREF, so $\left\{ \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 2\cr}, \pmatrix{3\cr 1\cr 2\cr 4\cr}\right\}$ will be a basis for the column space of $A$ (and the image of $T$).

Comment: That´s right. Suppose that i want to do this using 
a + 3b + 2c = w
b + c = x
a + 2b + c = y
2a + 4b + 2c = z

Is it okay?Supposedly yes, but i don´t know what to do with the result after doing GAUSS :S ---> w = x + y

Comment: You'll get conditions that the vectors have to satisfy. You should also get that $z=2y$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just Gaussian elimination:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1&3&2&w\\ 0&1&1&x\\ 1&2&1&y\\ 2&4&2&z\end{array}\right]
\to \left[\begin{array} {ccc|c} 1&3&2&w\\ 0&1&1&x\\ 0&-1&-1&y-w\\ 0&-2&-2&z-2w\end{array}\right]
\to \left[\begin{array} {ccc|c} 1&3&2&w\\ 0&1&1&x\\ 0&0&0&y-w+x\\ 0&0&0&z-2w+2x\end{array}\right]$$
You have two rows which are almost entirely zero. In order to guarantee that there is a solution,
you must have $y-w+x=0$ and $z-2w+2x=0$. Any vector that meets those conditions will be
in the column space.